# Read and write permissions on USB FTDI

Tags: pi-3, usb

I'm trying to send data over `/dev/ttyUSB0` by writing to it, and I'm looking for a commands which changes device permissions to Read and Write Only. I checked that device doesn't get any data.

on first terminal:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and echoing to dev/ttyUSB0:

```
echo "data" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I tried also to send in Python but also doesn't receive a data.

When I put `ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0` it returns me:

```
crwxrwxrwx 1 root dialout 188, 0 Feb 14 08:05 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Device only can send data but can't receive.

Comment: First and foremost, is there any data to be received? From what source? Have you tried to make a loopback?

Answer (score 0):

That’s not how it works. It’s not a normal file or FIFO.

Use py-serial, py3-serial, miniterm, cu, tip, perl-serial, or something like that.

If you want a CLI tool to use for piping data, I’ve used perl’s IPC::Open2 to pipe commands (and get replies). You can find examples with google. Thousands.

`echo status | python foo.py` will then do the trick.

You just need to add pi to dialout group BTW.

Here’s a Python 3 example I found. Adjust it to take STDIN as data to send. Scrap the rest.

——— foo.py ———

```py
import serial
import time
import re

# Change this to your serial port if needed - you can see the correct port in Arduino IDE
serialPort = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
serialSpeed = 9600 # ~960 bytes per second, a good default
txString = b'PING!\r\n'
rxString = b''

try:
    serialObj = serial.Serial( 
        serialPort,
        baudrate = serialSpeed,
        bytesize=8,
        parity = 'N',
        stopbits = 1,
        timeout=5
    ) 
except OSError:
    print( "ERROR: Could not set up serial connection on %s - exiting!" % serialPort )
    exit( 1 )

print ( "Connected to %s at %i baud. Hit CTRL+C to exit at any time ..." % ( serialPort, serialSpeed ) )

try:
    while True:
        if serialObj.write( txString ):
            print( "[*] Sent 'PING!', waiting for reply..." ) ;
        rxString = serialObj.readline() 
        rxString = rxString.rstrip()
        # ...
```

Comment: I added pi to dialout, see :

groups pi

`pi : pi adm tty dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio`

Comment: @lemming Looks good. You do know that Rx goes to Tx, and Tx goes to Rx?

Comment: sure, rs485 transmission is working well(writing from USB to RPi via rs485) but when I try to send data from rs485 to USB it doesn't work

Comment: Im changing RE ( is LOW when RPi receive a data and HIGH when transmit). I tried transmission in Python (at start RPI is receiver and FTDI is transmitter, when data is received by RPI i changed RE to HIGH and I set delay, next I send from RPI to FTDI and data isn't received)

Comment: What’s in your cmdline.txt?

Comment: /boot/cmdline.txt
`dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=74c799d5-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles`

Comment: @lemming Have a look at this https://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection

Comment: I think that my settings from cmdline.txt are good. I have ttyS0, never disabled ttyAMA0 (bluetooth)

Comment: @lemming Can you pop a shell over the serial cable?

Comment: @user2497 I fixed your formatting; you can indent blocks of code by pasting in, selecting the whole block and pressing Ctrl+K. This indents every line by 4 spaces and gets you code formatting. Backticks are just for inline code e.g. `one_liners` not big blocks. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Thanks, though I don’t use a real keyboard right now. I’ll bear it in mind.

Comment: You could also try wrapping the code in `<pre><code>` tags if that's easier; it should have the same effect as a limited subset of HTML is supported here.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Excellent, will do;)

Comment: @user2497 I have similiar code to yours but it doesn't work

Comment: @lemming Have you flashed another image (Raspbian fx)? Did you use raspi-config to enable serial? Have you tried another USB-TTL cable? Did you accidentally bake Rx/Tx pins with 5V instead of 3V3?

Comment: I didn't check with Rasbian fx. I enabled serial in raspi-config. I just have PIN connected to 3v3, I tried with another USB-TTL and it's the same problem